# Date Presets in Date Picker from Yesterday (Not from Today)

Tags: datetimepicker, datepicker

We need to add some date presets in our date picker, but our lookback window starts yesterday (we don't have data for "today").

The current options are:
[image]

So we need to remove "Today" as it's not an option
Yesterday - remains the same

What would be the best name for the following presets:
"Last 7 Days" -
"Last 30 Days"
"Quarter to Date" 
"Year to Date"
when data is only till yesterday

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be this, explain it in the title, then you don't have to muddy each description. The title text could be slightly different - but you get the meaning.

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. Maybe the message could be "Data is available up to midnight last night", if the data is timestamped and not just datestamped.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I will put the custom at the top. Placing arbitrary menu options at the top has high discoverability. If needed, 'Custom' may be enclosed in a pair of parenthesis as '(custom)'. Having special characters will automatically display the option at the top following ASCII character order.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.